# Redis Queue and Flask app on Heroku keeps timing out

Tags: flask, heroku, redis, chatbot, dyno

Hello fellow developers/mates.

I'm developing a chatbot that use Natural Language Processing (NLP) to transcribe text into a start & finish place.
It's hosted on Heroku and I use Flask for the web app.
I have to init my NLP by calling the GET /init route (with my favorite browser).
This init is a really time consuming process, so I decided to put it in a Redis Queue worker.

I have followed this tutorial here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq

The problem is : My web dyno on heroku always timeout, it seems that my init doesn't launch in the worker dyno but with the web dyno.

So I've got my app.py file :

```
from naturalLanguageProcessing import Nlp
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
import redis
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import abort

app = Flask(__name__)

""" Reset the NLP - delete the model & train it again - THIS IS THE TIME CONSUMING FUNCTION """
def resetNlp():
  NLP = Nlp()
  NLP.reset()
  NLP.train()

""" Init chatbot, IA, and others stuff """
@app.route('/init', methods=['GET'])
def init_entry():
  # Create redis queue
  q = Queue(connection=conn)

  # Queue reset nlp
  q.enqueue(resetNlp(), result_ttl=0, job_timeout=3600)

  return 'Chatbot initialized !'
```

This is my worker.py file :

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Connection(conn):
    print('Launching redis worker...')
    worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
    worker.work()
```

For my Procfile (to define the dynos), I have :

```
web: gunicorn app:app
worker: python -u worker.py
```

When I go on /init, this the response that I got from my web app :

```
heroku[router] error at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/init" request_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX fwd="xx.xxxx.xxxxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
app[web] CRITICAL [2020-11-03 19:37:38 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18)
app[web] INFO [2020-11-03 19:37:38 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
app[web] INFO [2020-11-03 19:37:38 +0000] [32] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32
```

I should just get a **Chatbot initialized !** response, with the redis worker keeps going in the init process....

Do you have, fellow developers, maybe an idea on how to fix my problem ?
Thank you for your futur help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have `q.enqueue(resetNlp, result_ttl=0, job_timeout=3600)`. So you pass a function that's going to be executed.
But what you do is you enqueue `resetNlp()`, which is effectively executing this function, which apparently takes enough time to evaluate, to timeout your HTTP request.

Comment: Ahah, alright it fixed my problem. I didn't really payed attention to this little point.
Thank you mate for that !